# Monitor bitcoind node traffic?

Tags: bitcoind, nodes, bandwidth

I was wondering how I would go about measuring the traffic being used on my network for the bitcoind node I am running. It's running  on the standard 8333 port, using linux as the OS.

I was looking at iftop which seems to be a tool for doing what I want to do, but I am specifically looking to only monitor traffic associated with the bitcoind node.

Basically I'm trying to see if my implementation of a QOS for the node is working properly.

Comment: This might help you: http://superuser.com/questions/604998/monitor-tcp-traffic-on-specific-port

Comment: I'm more looking for something that would show me the total bandwidth associated with that port. Like the upload and download speed being used on my network associated with port 8333. Maybe I'm missing it but this just seems to show the connections being made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RPC interface has a command `getpeerinfo` which will give a breakdown of upload and download metrics per connected peer.

```
  {  
    .. 
    "bytessent": 67619177,  
    "bytesrecv": 47229533,  
    "conntime": 1446238156,  
    ..  
  }
```

Totals for the session for all peers are available with `getnettotals`.

```
{
  "totalbytesrecv": 3664310320,
  "totalbytessent": 619085268,
  "timemillis": 1446521403149
}
```

`vnstat`is an external tool which will do system-wide monitoring and statistics collection over extremely long time periods. There is no per process breakdown, but it's a good thing to have around for a global view anyway.

```
eth0:
       Oct '15     70.88 GiB  /    2.65 GiB  /   73.53 GiB
       Nov '15     19.61 GiB  /  976.31 MiB  /   20.57 GiB  /  288.12 GiB
     yesterday      9.40 GiB  /  471.48 MiB  /    9.86 GiB
         today      1.13 GiB  /   66.35 MiB  /    1.20 GiB  /    8.49 GiB
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks! In-case someone comes here looking for the same info https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#bitcoin-core-apis